# Shiny : Download zip archive

Tags: r, shiny, zip

I am creating a Shiny application and I want to download my results in a zip archive. Before, it was working for me because I was using Rx34 bits. Unfortunately, it is not working since I have used Rx64bits.
I found some example which isn’t working for me:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('myTable1')
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$myTable1 <- DT::renderDataTable(iris)

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0("output", ".zip")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      k <- input$myTable1_rows_selected
      fs <- c()
      for (i in k) {
        path <- paste0(i, ".docx")
        rmarkdown::render("test.rmd", rmarkdown::word_document(), output_file = path)
        fs <- c(fs, path)
      }
      zip(file, fs)
    },
    contentType = "application/zip"
  )

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The error is the following one:

```
Warning: Error in zip: 'files' must a character vector specifying one or more filepaths
Stack trace (innermost first):
    54: zip
    53: download$func [#17]
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: <Promise>
Error : 'files' must a character vector specifying one or more filepaths
```

I work on R64bits in Windows 7. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When there are 0 rows selected, the call to zip fails because the `files` parameter, `fs`, is NULL.

Obviously, it depends what you want to do, but a quick and dirty hack is to explicitly create an empty file and place that in the output zip.

```
if (is.null(k)) {
    file.create('empty')
    zip(file, 'empty')
} else {
    zip(file, fs)
}
```

Comment: The problem is here:                                         rmarkdown::render("test.rmd", rmarkdown::word_document(), output_file = path)                                                                                                      and I have another error:  pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).

Comment: OK - so this is a different error to the original one. Do you have the file `test.rmd` visible in the folder where the code is?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have it. I just took this example from here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314582/how-to-download-multiple-reports-created-using-r-markdown-and-r-shiny-in-a-zip-f

Comment: Follow the instructions in the linked example to make the `test.rmd` file.

Comment: Thanks! Have a nice day.

Comment: Perhaps you could up-vote the answer since this is how this site works.