# Unable to use "Save as" function to save generated .CSV files and compile them into a zip file on Windows OS

Tags: r, shinyapps

I am having issues getting this code to work properly.

When i click on the save "results table" button in my ShinyApp, the files generated ended up in the same folder where my app.R files is located. The save as function appears , but it turns out that that function is obsolete. This function worked on Linux but not on Windows and I couldnt figure out the reason behind this.

Is this a glitch and if so , is there another way of writing the code to fix this issue on Windows?

I was being told that it is a glitch on Windows but it was a while back and I would want to check if there is a better way to write the code to get it to work properly.

***Code:***

```
#Download Results tables
output$downloadTable <- downloadHandler(
options(scipen = 999),
filename = function(){
"chromosome_count_tables.zip"
},
content = function(file){
compare_tbl_list <- compare_all(files = dataPlotInputBAMSegment(),
ref = ReferenceInputBAMSegment(), window = T,
per = T, compare_from_normal = FALSE)

  segment_plot_tbl_all <- segment_tbl_create_all(compare_tbl_list)
  segment_annotation_tbl_all <- segment_annotation_tbl_create_all(segment_plot_tbl_all)
  segment_annotation_tbl_all <- change_color_all(segment_annotation_tbl_all)

  final_tbl_all <- show_table_all(files = segment_plot_tbl_all, annotation_files = segment_annotation_tbl_all)

  files <- NULL;

  #loop through the sheets
  for (i in 1:length(final_tbl_all)){
    #write each sheet to a csv file, save the name
    fileName <- paste(input$fileBAMSegment[i,1],"_",i,".csv",sep = "")
    write.csv(final_tbl_all[i],fileName,row.names = F)
    files <- c(fileName,files)
  }
  #create the zip file
  system2("zip", args=(paste(file,files,sep=" ")))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just want to update here that I managed to resolve it on my own.

The code will only work if you open the shinyapp through a browser and not through the viewer pane or Rstudio viewer in Windows OS. It works normally in Ubuntu.

Refer to : [How to download multiple reports created using R markdown and R shiny in a zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314582/how-to-download-multiple-reports-created-using-r-markdown-and-r-shiny-in-a-zip-f)

PS: Unsure if you need to also install RTools and add it to your devtools package.

Just in case it is needed , you can refer to :

https://rstats.wtf/set-up-an-r-dev-environment.html  and
[https://ohdsi.github.io/Hades/rSetup.html#:~:text=your%20Start%20Menu.-,Installing%20RTools,Select%20the%20default%20options%20everywhere](https://ohdsi.github.io/Hades/rSetup.html#:%7E:text=your%20Start%20Menu.-,Installing%20RTools,Select%20the%20default%20options%20everywhere).

Comment: Just want to give an update that you will need to install Rtools then open it through the external browser in order for this function to work properly.  Function works normally on Linux without any extra steps needed